# How to initialize field in class C#/.Net in efficient and safe way?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, properties, initialization

Here is two classes `MyClass` and `Helper`, in order to have one instance of `Helper` class in `MyClass` it could be initialize with property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IHelper _helper;
    private IHelper Helper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_helper != null)
            {
                _helper = new Helper();
            }
            return _helper;
        }
    }
}
```

or constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IHelper Helper { get; set; }

    MyClass()
    {
        Helper = new Helper();
    }
}
```

---

**The question**: What is benefits and potential issues with each solution? Is it some other better options?

---

Comment: Second way is more efficient. You have one less `IHelper` object.

Comment: In first example `IHelper Helper` is only alias for getting `_helper` value, what is the point of that?

Comment: "You have one less IHelper object"? Huh? You create the same number of objects either way. (Unless you never get `Helper`, in which case the first avoids creating any.)

Comment: The previous answers by "dasblinkenlight" and "ChrFin" are good so I won't add on them. If you want further reading about this search the Factory Method Creational Design Pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method

Comment: Second way doesn't have a potential multithreading bug...

Comment: I think it is a mistake to mark this question as opinion-bases.
I was looking for problems and issues my solution could give to me.
What is more important - the answer, I got from dasblinkenlight and ChrFin, was helpful and clarifying for me and I believe could help other community members.
However I modify a question a bit to remove all misunderstandings and I kindly ask you to vote for **reopen** it.

Comment: @Alex: As asked, not really. There's no problem to be solved here. "The good and bad of X" is still inherently a matter of opinion. And "When would i use X" is too broad. The question might have better luck on [softwareengineering.se], but i wouldn't be surprised if it were already asked and answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two approaches are not identical:

- The first approach creates `_helper` on the first read; if `Helper` property is never accessed, no instance of `Helper` is created
- The second approach creates `_helper` eagerly, meaning that you would have an instance of `Helper` in each instance of `MyClass`.

The choice between these two behaviors is based on your requirements, not on an opinion. Note that you can use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achieve the behavior from your first example with less code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Lazy<IHelper> _helper = new Lazy<IHelper>(() => new Helper());
    private IHelper Helper {
        get => _helper.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need a property `private IHelper Helper` in this your example? Looks like here is redundant.

Comment: @Alex I kept the property for compatibility with your original class. You could definitely get rid of it, and use `_helper.Value` directly.

Comment: What is your opinion about performance issues with Lazy<T> mentioned by ChrFin?

Comment: @Alex There is no way to tell if it's going to make a difference in your specific case without measuring. It's definitely not free, but it's not a CPU hog either. Unless you are in a tight loop, or in a highly concurrent environment, you wouldn't see a measurable difference.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, you were contributing answering this question, don't you think it should be reopened?

Comment: @Alex Of course I do! I think it should have never been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Those two examples don't do the same and so there is no "matter of style", but of "how should it work". The difference is minor but still there is one:

In your first example the instance of `Helper` is only created if it is accessed at least once, but in your second example it is always created even if it is not needed.
Also in the second example it has a private setter an thus can be changed later on in time again.

IMO you should use the first one if it is not always used and the second one if it is needed every time, but then make the property read-only (remove the setter - setting in the constructor still works if your compiler is up to date).

Another shorter version for the first one I tend to use in such cases (`Lazy<T>` has some minor overhead and do not use it for "singleton like patterns"):

```
private IHelper helper;
public IHelper Helper => helper ?? (helper = new Helper());
```

*NOTE*: This code-example is NOT thread-safe, so if that is a requirement use the example from dasblinkenlight. Here it could happen that two instances of `Helper` are created if the property is accessed the same time by two threads and the second one is then set to `helper` in the end. If that is not the case or no problem it is safe to use. If I remember correctly the thread-safety is also the main reason why `Lazy<T>` creates some measurable overhead which led us to not use it in all cases.

Comment: Why is is not suggested to use Lazy<T> ? What is consequence?

Comment: I'd recommend using `Lazy<T>` - especially if your class needs to be threadsafe.

Comment: @Alex As already stated in the answer above the code: There is a minor overhead (we use/used them a lot and it was measurable) by using `Lazy<T>` in comparison to my example. So depending on the actual use-case (e.g. as mentioned by Matthew if it needs to be thread-safe) we use one of the two possibilities.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks - did not thought of that, as the problem was also present in the OPs code...